# Would "mon ami et je" be first-person singular or plural?

Tags: noms

I was writing a brief assignment about me and my friend. I was using a reflexive verb with the subject noun "mon ami et je". Would this be treated as singular ("je") or plural ("nous")?

Comment: Actually, "me and my friend ..." is incorrect in English too, even if used a lot. It should be "my friend and I ..." (or "I and my friend ...", although placing "my friend" first is more polite). And in that case, as already answered "I" is translated by "moi".

Comment: @AlexisWilke: this is beside the point, but the way the OP uses "me and my friend" — "about me and my friend" — is perfectly correct in English.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, *about my friend and I* is an example of [hypercorrection](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1051/23719).

Answer (score 6):

You can't say *Mon ami et <s>***je***</s>*, that would be a grammatical mistake. Unlike in English where both ***my friend and I*** and ***my friend and me*** are competing and often used either as a subject or an object despite presciptivism that tells they should be specialized, French always use ***mon ami et moi*** whether it is subject or object. See this [interesting paper](http://fine.me.uk/Emonds/wholetext.xml) about the English usage (found in [this reply](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1061/23719)).

*Mon ami et **moi*** is then the only right form and the first person plural is expected:

> *Mon ami et moi arriverons demain.*  (no comma)
> *Mon ami et moi, nous arriverons demain.*  (comma)

More commonly:

> *Mon ami et moi, on arrive demain.*

With a reflexive verb, as Luke commented:

> *Mon ami et moi nous sommes parlé.* (rare)
> *Mon ami et moi, nous nous sommes parlé.*

and again:

> *Mon ami et moi, on s'est parlé.*

See also: [Pronoms sujets : « elle et moi » ou « elle et je » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8465/pronoms-sujets-elle-et-moi-ou-elle-et-je) and [Use of nous when moi is used in the subject](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43788/use-of-nous-when-moi-is-used-in-the-subject)

Comment: How would we use this with a reflexive verb? "Mon ami et moi nous <verb> <indirect object>"?

Comment: @Someone While you could do that, I think it's more natural to repeat the subject pronoun as well. Mon ami et moi, nous (nous) sommes fait un petit déjeuner ensemble. Mon ami et moi, nous nous sommes parlé.

Comment: @Luke I guess you already know that but I want to make clear that there is never a comma between a subject and its verb so your example is *Mon ami et moi(,) nous (nous) sommes [...]*

Comment: @jlliagre Pourtant je suis certain que je l'ai vu de temps à autre pour des raisons stylistiques ? C'est-à-dire pour marquer une pause ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Une pause est inattendue à cet endroit. On peut en marquer une en cas d'incise: *Mon ami et moi, dit-il, nous sommes rencontrés pour un petit-déjeuner* ou si le sujet est un énumération : *Mon ami, sa femme, moi, nous retrouverons au restaurant* mais c'est une phrase un peu forcée. Il y a sûrement d'autres cas particuliers mais la règle générale est qu'on ne met jamais de virgules entre les éléments essentiels d'une phrase. [Bescherelle](https://bescherelle.ca/virgule/)

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, j'avais mal compris -- le virgule que tu contestes est celui qui apparaîtrait quand il n'y a qu'un « nous ». Oui, certainement que celui-là serait erroné (tandis que l'autre servirait à introduire une forme d'apposition entre les deux énonciations du sujet).